# Why pyramid_celery needs to bootstrap a pyramid WSGI application?

Tags: celery, pyramid, wsgi

Why pyramid_celery bootstraps the pyramid WSGI application using given PasteDeploy configuration file and is not using the returned environment? What is the purpose of this call?

[pyramid_celery@Github - source code line using pyramid.paster.bootstrap](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_celery/blob/master/pyramid_celery/commands/__init__.py#L16)

```
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
from celery.app import default_app


class CommandMixin(object):
    preload_options = ()

    def setup_app_from_commandline(self, argv):
        if len(argv) < 2:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'No configuration file specified.'
            sys.exit(1)
        bootstrap(argv[1])
        self.app = default_app
        return argv[:1] + argv[2:]
```

References

- [pyramid.paster.bootstrap](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/paster.html#pyramid.paster.bootstrap)

pyramid docs on use cases bootstrapping WSGI applications

- [Writing a script](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#writing-a-script)
- [Making Your Script into a Console Script](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#making-your-script-into-a-console-script)

Comment: I believe this is done to set up various threadlocal structures that allow the user to call various Pyramid functions.

Comment: Please extend your thoughts in an answer. I will add an answer too with insights from last months. Thank you.